# Headless chrome using Selenium-Java running tests in normal UI mode of browser

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, headless, google-chrome-headless

I am trying to run my application in headless mode using Chrome Browser, Selenium and Java. But it open a new chrome instance and start running the script in normal UI mode(can see the execution)

Is there anything wrong in code or browser compatibility.

OS - Windows 10,
Chrome Version -  85.0.4183.121

Below is my code -

```
package XYZ;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
public class Test{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                "C:\\Users\\TestUser\\Desktop\\SeleniumWorkspace\\ABC\\chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("headless");
        options.addArguments("window-size=1400,800");       
        options.addArguments("disable-gpu")
        //options.addArguments("--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=1400,800","--ignore-certificate-errors");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);   
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");
        System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I can see you are missing `"--"` before passing the arguments in the code. Below is the correct code to use headless chrome while running your automated cases:

```
    package XYZ;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
public class Test{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                "C:\\Users\\TestUser\\Desktop\\SeleniumWorkspace\\ABC\\chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--headless");     
        options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
        options.addArguments("--window-size=1400,800");  
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);   
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");
        System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());
    }
}
```

For me this is working fine. I hope this solves your probelm.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that as well but issue was with selenium webdriver version. After updating the selenium webdriver ot works for both cases.

Comment: So, right now after you have updated your chrome version to 85.0.4183.121, you have are facing this issue. Means headless option is not working?

Comment: Actually I was using  chrome version as 85.0.4183.121 only earlier, but my selenium-java dependency was not updated. So i have updated the selenium-java dependency to 3.141.59 and I am able to run my code in headless mode.

Answer (score 0):

This is the new way to do it:

```java
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--headless=new");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: What do you mean by _the new way to do it_? Is the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64046452/headless-chrome-using-selenium-java-running-tests-in-normal-ui-mode-of-browser/64046989#64046989) no longer applicable?